# Print version on A4 page and save as PDF

Tags: html, css, pdf

I am stuck at one place. I have an HTML page but I wanna only one DIV on print page with print button and save as PDF in with save button as bellow.

```
<div class="abc">
    Here are some words
    <div class="def">
        Some more words
        <div class="ghi">
            This is I want for print on A4 page and save as PDF but like my letterhead with logo and other detail like microsoft word have header and footer. I want to header and footer add in header.php and footer.php but only on print and save as PDF. And this div class in the middle of letter.
            <button>Click for print</button>
            <button>Click to save as PDF</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wanna print version as Letter head
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate tool to create PDF from HTML and it need to be on the server side. Possible solutions for PHP are discussed in [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

If you don't really **need** PDF but only a printable version, I would recommend using CSS media queries for printing. You can hide all unwanted parts very easy with it and use the browser print button:

```
@media print {
   button { display: none; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't know about @media print. 
Can I have some coding of it?

Comment: That already *is* the coding. It's css. You could include it in your HTML by using a `<style>` tag with this content.

Comment: Did you succeed with this info? Or is there still something missing?